# WebRTC H264 video blob not displaying

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, h.264

I have spend some weeks reading on the internet and trying to solve this but it has been imposible for me.

I have a native app offering a WebRTC video stream, signaling and SDP offer/answer sharing is done using peer_connection_server.exe from webrtc samples. I want to stream H.264 but I can only make VP8/VP9 work and just in Firefox, not in Chrome.

I have a modified HTML native-to-browser-test.html test example atteched here.

Everything is running on Windows 10 64 bits.

The issue is:
Using VP8 and VP9:
-Using Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) the video element (blob:null/XXXXX) is displaying properly.
-Using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 nothing is displayed in the video element.

Using H.264 only in the SDP:
-Using Firefox 52.0.1 (32-bit) nothing is displayed in the video element.
-Using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 nothing is displayed in the video element.

My question is, is it something that should be working or is it work in progress? How can I configure the browsers to accept my stream? Does anyone have WebRTC H264 streaming to a web browser from a native APP?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the Answer SDP and after that the ICE candidates that each browser throw are differente.

Firefox:
onicecandidate:{"sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"video","candidate":"candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 192.168.0.12 61861 typ host"}
onicecandidate:{"sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"video","candidate":"candidate:1 1 UDP 1686052863 79.108.97.192 61861 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.12 rport 61861"}

Chrome:
onicecandidate:{"sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"video","candidate":"candidate:4285824471 1 udp 2113937151 192.168.0.12 52199 typ host generation 0 ufrag 8isL network-cost 50"}
onicecandidate:{"sdpMLineIndex":0,"sdpMid":"video","candidate":"candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677729535 79.108.97.192 52199 typ srflx raddr 192.168.0.12 rport 52199 generation 0 ufrag 8isL network-cost 50"}

Are chrome ICE candidates malformated for some reason? What could the be reasons?

Best regards :)